# How to create sub entities in mySQL? employee and chef

Tags: mysql

I am currently working on a small project in mySQL.I have a table called employee;ID, FirstName, ...)
I want to create a sub entity of this employee table and name it chef. chef has a special attributes: chef( cuisine, shift type,..)
What is the best way to achieve this? Thanks

Comment: Create separate table which is referenced to `employee` and stores employeeID and specific chief columns.

Comment: @Akina that's just one of the possible solutions

Comment: @Shadow Of course.